# Text is getting messed up on the Screen

Tags: text

My text is getting messed up on the screen in random way. Depending on where I click or what I do some text on the screen gets messed up. I can't place any image  because of the reputation points, but it's a random blur.

Another issue that might be the reason of this blur is a rare but constant message of crash that keeps popping up. I forgot to get the details the last time but it says that the system has encountered an internal error.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem when I installed extra themes and used them. If you have done so, you should revert to the basic theme and test it. In case the problem still persists, provide more error details so someone who has more knowledge can help you on this.

Comment: For some unknown reason after restarting the PC two times things are working fine, no more blurs, no more messed up texts. Thanks for the help, I would upvote you if it wasn't for my little to low amount of reputation points.